# Spring dynamic async

Tags: spring, asynchronous

Trying to have a dynamic number of async processes running in Spring 2.0.5. I do have it working on a fixed number but need the flexibility.

the current methods are:

in class AsyncFactoryService:

```
   public void doAsyncBetter(long rowsPerBucket) throws InterruptedException, SQLException, ExecutionException {
    List<Bucket> buckets = sourceData01Service.bucketsByRowsPerBucket(rowsPerBucket);
    AsyncDataLoadService[] asyncDataLoadServiceArray = new AsyncDataLoadService[buckets.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
      asyncDataLoadServiceArray[i] = new AsyncDataLoadService();
      asyncDataLoadServiceArray[i].loadSourceData01(buckets.get(i));
    }
  }
```

in class AsyncDataLoadService

```
  @Autowired SourceData01Service sourceData01Service;
  
  @Async
  public Future<String> loadSourceData01(Bucket bucket) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("(loadSourceData01) [Thread id => %d, bucket => %s]",Thread.currentThread().getId(), bucket.toString()));
    List<SourceData01> sourceData01s = null;
    sourceData01s = sourceData01Service.rowsByBucket(bucket);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String info = String.format("finish sourceData01s.size() => %d, Thread id => %d", sourceData01s.size(), Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return new AsyncResult<>(info);
  }
```

this fails with

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demo.service.AsyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(AsyncDataLoadService.java:35) ~[classes/:?]
    at demo.service.AsyncFactoryService.doAsyncBetter(AsyncFactoryService.java:43) ~[classes/:?]
    at demo.RunApp.run(RunApp.java:39) ~[classes/:?]
```

As it seems in the service the sourceData01Service is null.

When I try with a fixed number like

```
public void doAsync(long rowsPerBucket) throws InterruptedException, SQLException, ExecutionException {
    List<Bucket> buckets = sourceData01Service.bucketsByRowsPerBucket(rowsPerBucket);
    Future<String> process0 = asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(buckets.get(0));
    Future<String> process1 = asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(buckets.get(1));
    Future<String> process2 = asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(buckets.get(2));
    Future<String> process3 = asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(buckets.get(3));
    Future<String> process4 = asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(buckets.get(4));
    while(!(process0.isDone()) && !(process2.isDone()) && !(process3.isDone()) && !(process4.isDone())) {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    LOGGER.info("Process 0 => " + process0.get());
    LOGGER.info("Process 1 => " + process1.get());
    LOGGER.info("Process 2 => " + process2.get());
    LOGGER.info("Process 3 => " + process3.get());
    LOGGER.info("Process 4 => " + process4.get());
  }
```

it works as expected but in my case the number of buckets is dependent on the number of rows in the table so I do not know how many buckets there will be. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service (`sourceData01Service`) injection in `AsyncDataLoadService` didn't happen as the application is creating the instance of `AsyncDataLoadService` (in the factory class) instead of spring creating it.

We can modify the implementation to let spring create the required instance.

```
@Component
class AsyncDataLoadService {
      @Autowired SourceData01Service sourceData01Service;
      
      @Async
      public Future<String> loadSourceData01(Bucket bucket) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {
        LOGGER.info(String.format("(loadSourceData01) [Thread id => %d, bucket => %s]",Thread.currentThread().getId(), bucket.toString()));
        List<SourceData01> sourceData01s = null;
        sourceData01s = sourceData01Service.rowsByBucket(bucket);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String info = String.format("finish sourceData01s.size() => %d, Thread id => %d", sourceData01s.size(), Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return new AsyncResult<>(info);
      }
 }
```

We can then change the factory class implementation to autowire `AsyncDataLoadService` and submit the job to be executed (in this case loadSourceData01).

Since `asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01` is annotated with `@Async`, every call to that method will be executed in a separate thread. By default spring use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` that fires up new thread for every invocation. Configure thread pool implementation if required.

```
@Component
class AsyncFactoryService {

   @Autowired
   AsyncDataLoadService asyncDataLoadService;

    public void doAsyncBetter(long rowsPerBucket) throws InterruptedException, SQLException, ExecutionException {
        List<Bucket> buckets = sourceData01Service.bucketsByRowsPerBucket(rowsPerBucket);
        for(int i = 0; i < buckets.size(); i++) {
          asyncDataLoadService.loadSourceData01(buckets.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```